# When executing a command on a Kubernetes Pod via kubectl exec, how can the Pod identity the user?

Tags: kubernetes

Assume I'm using `kubectl exec` to run a command inside a Kubernetes Pod. Is there any way for the executed process to know who I am?

Comment: Yes, the process can be set up to use the Kubernetes API, which may be used to find out who sent the command and extract their identity. The API's authentication context, which is filled with the user's credentials when the command is started, can be used to determine the user identity.

Comment: @CoolNetworking What specific API could the process use to find out who sent the command?

Comment: You need to inspect it from inside through logs and I guess that is the only option as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes Pods are not Virtual Machines, so not something you typically can "log in" to.
But you can try using `runAsUserName` in pod yaml.

Comment: Well, the `runAsUserName` would have nothing to do with the user running `kubectl exec`, or would it? So it doesn't really solve my problem of identifying the user calling `kubectl exec`, right?